# N台クラスタの時刻のずれを計算したい

Tags: サーバー管理

今、N台(N=10前後)構成のクラスタがあるとします。それぞれのノードには、 ssh でアクセスができます。

このとき、これらノードの間でどれぐらい時刻がずれているのかを計算したいのですが、これはどうやったら求められるでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

各々のノードから、同じNTPサーバへ問い合わせをさせ、時刻のずれを取得するというのはどうでしょうか。
例えば`ntpdate`コマンドの`-q`オプションで、

```
ntpdate -q ntp.example.com
```

とすれば、NTPサーバとのずれが`offset -0.010427 sec`のような形式で取得できます。

もちろん各々のノード側でNTPサーバを動かしてもいいですし、ずれを計算するくらいなら通常のNTPの使い方で時計を合わせてしまうのがよい気もします。

Comment: FWIW: 手元だと、 `/usr/sbin/ntpdate -q ntp.example.com` で実行できました。 (sbin なので、通常ユーザーではパスが通っていない。が、 sudo でなくても実行できる)